# Kotlin - Is there a smart way to throw NotImplementedError for all the methods of a class?

Tags: reflection, kotlin, resultset, sqlbulkcopy, packed-decimal

I need to implement an interface (`ResultSet`) having hundreds of methods. 
For now, I'm going to implement only a subset of these methods, throwing a `NotImplementedError` for the others.

In Java I found two solutions:

1. Create an abstract class `AbstractResultSet` implementing `ResultSet`, declaring all methods to throw `NotImplementedError`. No hacks, but a lot of boilerplate code.
2. Use `Proxy.newProxyInstance` to implement all methods together in the `InvocationHandler`. Less code but also less immediate to use for other coders.

Is there a third option in Kotlin?

In my case, I need to implement a a `ResultSet` over an IBM dataset (with packed decimals, binary fields, zoned numbers, rows with variable length, etc.) to import it in a SQLServer via `SQLServerBulkCopy`. I don't know which `ResultSet` methods are called by this class, so, for now, I'm going to implement only the "most used" methods, logging the calls to unimplemented method.

Answer (score 3):

Checkout the standard TODO function which marks a todo and also throws a NotImplementedError

```
/**
 * Always throws [NotImplementedError] stating that operation is not implemented.
 *
 * @param reason a string explaining why the implementation is missing.
 */
@kotlin.internal.InlineOnly
public inline fun TODO(reason: String): Nothing = throw NotImplementedError("An operation is not implemented: $reason")
```

Usage:

```
fun foo() {
        TODO("It will be soon")
    }
```

With this way you can also find notImplemented fetures using the IDE "todo" tab. It is a plus.

Comment: This answer is an improving of @Andrew solutions, but basically shares the same idea. I would extend the interface providing a default implementation with TODO for each method. It's simple, the IDE would do the job, but I would produce a lot of boilerplate code.

Answer (score 1):

You can crate an Interface `MyResultSet` which inherit from `ResultSet`, and implement all methords to throw NotImplementedError. This is like your first solution in Java, but it's now an interface not a class, and give you more flexibility. Hope help.

```
interface MyResultSet : ResultSet {
    fun bar() ...
    fun foo() {
        throw NotImplementedError()
    }
}
```